# How to add a border-bottom similar to Yahoo! when you scroll the page?

Tags: javascript, css

How to add a border similar to Yahoo! when you scroll the page?
I would like to .has-border to the nav element.

Jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/hvz22/

HTML

```
<nav>
</nav>
    <main>
        <div id="content">
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        <p>Something</p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

CSS

```
nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background:blue;
    height:50px;
}

main{
    width:1200px;
    left:auto;
    right:auto;
    background:lightgray;
    height:2000px;
    min-height:100%;
}

.has-border{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: A link to an example would be good.

Comment: There is a link jsfiddle.net

Comment: An example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I would like to add ".has-border" to the nav element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by attaching a scroll event to the window and checking the scroll position.

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
       if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 0){
          jQuery('nav').addClass('border');
       }
       else{
          jQuery('nav').removeClass('border');
       }
    });
```

Heres an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hvz22/14/